# How to read multiple input lines in C# v4.2.6 console?

Tags: c#, string, console-application

I want to read multiple input lines in C# v2.4.6 I have entered 3 input lines like below

```
4
2 5 6 3
20 40 90 50
```

I use `string line=Console.ReadLine()`

The first time it reads 4 then I use:

```cs
string abc=Console.ReadLine();
string xyz=Console.ReadLine();
```

but the output shows `abc[0]=2` and `xyz[0]=2`

Please suggest any solution

Comment: can't you read all data in a single line as a string then split with space and put on a specific variable.

Comment: these input lines should be entered in 3 different lines so I have to read them in 3 different strings

Comment: Can you format the input data properly so we can see what you mean by 3 input lines? At the moment it shows as 1 long line.

Comment: in the first line only 4 is entered in second line 2 5 6 3 are entered and in third line 20 40 90 50 are entered

Comment: Any solution to what? The `ReadLine()` method is doing exactly what it's supposed to: read a line of text input. Each time you call it, you'll get a new line of text. You can't change how `ReadLine()` works. But you _can_ change what you do with the `string` values it returns. So, **what have you tried?** What would you like the text to look like when you're done? What _specifically_ are you having trouble figuring out?

Comment: I want the output as abc[0]=2 and xyz[0]=20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the below code suggested by Pankaj Rawat and it's working.

```
   string line=Console.ReadLine()
   string[] abc = line.Split(' ');
   int y=Convert.ToInt32(abc[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Console application `ReadLine` method won't read data from multiple lines. you can read data like this

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter your first name.");
        string firstName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your last name.");
        string lastName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your job title.");
        string jobTitle = Console.ReadLine();
```

Or

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter your data");
            string firstline = Console.ReadLine();
            string secondline = Console.ReadLine();
            string thirdline = Console.ReadLine();

            string input = string.Concat(firstline, secondline, thirdline);
```

Comment: I have to input only these data in 3 lines one by one

Comment: I am getting this and used the same code but I want each element in string separately like abc[0]=2,abc[1]=5 ,... and same for xyz[0]=20,xyz[1]=40

Comment: you can use split function e.g. string[] stringArray = firstline.Split(' ');

Comment: var val1 = Convert.ToInt32(stringArray[0]);

Answer (score 0):

Use Following Code for multiple inputs:

Use spaces for multiple inputs:

```
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Tokens : ");

    string Token = Console.ReadLine();
    string[] T = Token.Split(' ');

    Console.WriteLine("Tokens : ");
    for (int i = 0; i < T.Length; i++)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(T[i]);

    }
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?